# Trouble deploying jar file with images

Tags: java, image, deployment, embedded-resource, executable-jar

I am trying to deploy my Java GUI as a runnable jar file. The problem is that none of the images or even the shapes I've created with Swing & AWT show up when I run the jar file. Can anyone tell me the proper way to export a Java application with images and shapes? The following code calls in random images.

```
int randomImage = (int)(Math.random() * 8);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/images/" +randomImage + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: *"or even the shapes"* I am guessing the shapes are not appearing because the code fails on `NullPointerException` (re the images) before betting to that part.  Run it from the command line where you can observe the error output.

Answer (score 3):

By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`. Namely:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/path/to/the.resource");
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer! I will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @trashgod  The link to the answer is good.  The answer is exemplary.  We have to be careful not to make it too Java oriented though, since it is a tag used for a number of other languages that can also use embedded resources.  That link nicely 'completes' the Java side of it, I think.